# Setting a role as fileOrganizer for shared/team google drive item failing for shared/team drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Trying to set permission as "fileOrganizer" for a user on a shared google drive folder, but the v3 (and v2) API giving error `FileOrganizer role is only valid for shared drives`, and I could NOT find a way to specify that the folder is on a shared drive.

It is possible to set same permission via UI.

Code

```
gapi.client.drive.permissions
      .create({
        fileId: folderId,
        sendNotificationEmail: false,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        role: 'fileOrganizer' // 'writer' works
        type: 'user',
        emailAddress
      }).then(
```

API Response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fileOrganizerOnNonTeamDriveNotSupported",
    "message": "FileOrganizer role is only valid for shared drives."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "FileOrganizer role is only valid for shared drives."
 }
}
```

Points to note

1. For a shared drive, [some API documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives) requires setting "supportsAllDrives" parameter to true, but [API document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) indicates it as deprecated.
2. This [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#specific_roles_for_shared_drives) explains Specific roles for shared drives, but there is no way to mention that permissions.create request is for a shared drive.
3. [files.list API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) has option to pass driveId by setting 'corpora': 'drive' which indicates a shared drive, but similar option is not available for `permissions.create`.

I tried various combinations like passing driveId without any luck.
Are there any other options?

Comment: Link to google issue : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152118538

Answer (score 1):

### The role `fileOrganizer` is only a valid choice for the whole shared drive rather than a single file on this drive

What you can do instead:

- Either give the user the `role` `fileOrganizer` for the whole drive (specifying the shared Drive Id as file Id)
- Or give the user permission for the specific file, specifying `writer`, `reader`, `commenter` or `owner` (for the latter case specifying `transferOwnership` `true`) as `role`.

Comment: Thanks for response, Please note that from the UI it is possible to set a user as fileOrganizer for a particular folder. So based on your answer, can I say that setting user as fileOrganizer via API is not supported?

Comment: You can make a test by sharing a folder with a user with the option `Can organize, add & edit`. In the next step, you can list(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) the permissions of the folder and confirm that the assigned role is `writer`, not `fileOrganizer`. Unfortunately, the documentation and method names are quite misleading.

Comment: From UI if I set fileOrganizer, the permission list API returns fileOrganizer correctly. Also setting "owner" role on this folder gives error `Owner role is invalid for shared drive items.`

Comment: Are you sure that you talking about a `folder` inside a shared drive rather than about a  `drive` which is listed under `Shared drives`? Because for folders inside a shared drive the sharing option is disabled, see here: [https://miro.medium.com/max/407/1*DJulsM54jW7A5IU7ll4pdw.png](https://miro.medium.com/max/407/1*DJulsM54jW7A5IU7ll4pdw.png)
https://support.google.com/a/thread/11036891?hl=en

Comment: yes, check my previous comments, trying to set "owner" role on same folder gives error `Owner role is invalid for shared drive items`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in API, awaiting response on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152118538

Comment: I believe `Owner role is invalid for shared drive items` is intended behavior for folders on the shared drive. So when you try to share a folder on a shared drive from the Drive UI - you do NOT see [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/407/1%2ADJulsM54jW7A5IU7ll4pdw.png)? Are you sure the folder you can share from the UI is on a shared drive rather than "Shared with me"? Please show a screenshot of how you share a folder on a shared drive from the UI.

Comment: Yes, it is on shared drive. From the UI, I can set the same permission on that folder.

Comment: Would you provide a screenshot of what it looks like on your drive when you right click on the folder?

Comment: Can't share the screenshot, as this is on a customer's environment

Comment: based on confirmation from team, this is currently unsupported and will be available in future

Comment: "fileOrganizer" does work for single folders inside shared drive. "organizer" does not.